# Disabling open-in-view in spring boot makes CORS stop working

Tags: spring-boot, cors, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a working CORS configuration in my spring boot app. I wanted to manage transactions on my own, so I decided to disable open-in-view in my application.yaml by setting it to false:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
```

CORS config:

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        configuration.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        configuration.addExposedHeader("Concurrency");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

For some reason I can not figure out, this prevents the CORS from working properly, browser keeps saying that:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/batch' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Even though that header is actually present in the pre-flight OPTIONS request. Tomcat logs no exceptions or log entries of interest that could possibly explain this.

Comment: are you sure that you don't get any LazyInitializationExceptions now?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am fairly certain I do not. The service method is marked `@Transactional`, the controller properly returns the list of DTOs.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli you were right, but spring wrapped that LazyInitializationException in many others, and then just displayed 500 - internal server error, and nothing was logged. So if you want a correct answer, write it as a proper response.